# Как открыть доступ к серверу по SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Поставил дома сервер на ubuntu20.04, установил ssh-server. В пределах локальной сети я могу подключиться к серверу по ssh, но из вне уже нет. Как открыть доступ, чтобы можно было по ip:22 подключиться из любой другой сети, скажем, с телефона или ноутбука?

openssh-server запущен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно сконфирурировать на маршрутизаторе Port Forwarding: порт 22 на внешнем интерфейсе маршрутизатор должен пересылать на порт 22 на сервере. Как именно это сделать зависит очень сильно от маршрутизатора. Да, и у маршрутизатора должен быть статический глобально маршрутизируемый адрес.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую воспользоваться утилитой ngrok.
https://ngrok.com/ - публичный адрес для вашего порта во внутренней сети. За скромную плату они предоставят статичный адрес в рамках своих серверов.
Вам необходимо будет только запустить инстанс ngroka у себя локально